# How to encrypt SD card on Nokia 6.1?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, encryption, android-one, nokia-6

Is there any way to encrypt the SD card on Nokia 6.1?

I didn't find any option to do it.
(The current Android version is Android One 8.1.0)

Product page: [Nokia 6.1](https://www.nokia.com/en_gb/phones/nokia-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing it with native settings. Alternatives below :

- From Android 6.0 onwards we have [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage) wherein the entire memory (phone + ext SD) is treated as one memory unit and is encrypted. It is highly recommended to read the [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) 
  and understand pros and cons before doing this (IMHO, it's a rotten idea but that's me)
- Browse through the tools available for file / folder / media encryption from Izzy's [app repository](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_encrypt) and pick your choice